# Matching First and Second Derivatives: Taylor Series

Tags: approximation

I have

$$
f(x) = \sqrt{\ln\left(a\cosh^{2}(mx)(1+bx^{2})\right)}
$$

If I expand this as a series I should get something of the form

$$
\sqrt{\ln a}+gx^{2}+\mathcal{O}(x^{4})
$$

but I'm having real difficulty getting Mathematica to give me the necessary Taylor series of $f(x)$. Can anyone help? I only really need $g$, the later coefficients aren't necessary. Perhaps there's a reason why Mathematica has a problem?

Comment: so you were unsuccessful in finding a better function than $\cosh(x)$?

Comment: For me, Mathematica immediately gave me the result using Series. I am using Mathematica 7

Comment: A work around is to calculate $f''(0)/2$, the second-order Taylor coefficient. That also works. The answer is $g=\frac{2b+m^2}{4\ln(a)}$

Comment: perhaps you could give me the $x^4$ term so I can work out b and m?

Comment: I have a Taylor series of another equation and need to solve for the three variables b,m and a, so I actually need three equations if you can give me the third? Thanks for this